# Sobolev space, cut off function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am looking for a function.

Let $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ be $(1,2)$-Sobolev space on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Can we construct the following function?

> $\chi \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ such that $\chi=1$ $dx$-a.e. on $K_{1}$ and
>   $\chi=0$ $dx$-a.e. on $K_{2}$, 
>   where $K_{1},K_{2}$ are closed and disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. **and Lebesgue measure of $K_{1}$ is finite.**

It is known that the existence of the following function (Urysohn's lemma)

$F \in C(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ such that $F=1$ on $K_{1}$ and $F=0$ on $K_{2}$, where $K_{1},K_{2}$ are closed and disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

If you know, please tell me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $K_1$ has infinite measure, this is impossible, simply because $\chi $ would already satisfy $\|\chi\|_2=\infty $.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since I didn't think such a case, I'll correct this question.

Comment: If $K_1$ is bounded, or more generaly, if the distance between $K_1$ and $K_2$ is strictly positive, then it is possible.